# ProgressDialog issue in Recyclerview Adaptor android

Tags: android, kotlin, progressdialog

I try to click on recyclerview item and show progressDilog for "please wait.."and intent pass , but when i press back button my progress dilog continous disply. Here is my code :-

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val progressDilog = ProgressDialog(context)
            progressDilog.setMessage("Please Wait..")
            progressDilog.setCancelable(false)
            progressDilog.show()
            myClickListner!!.onItemClickListener(position)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: No , @HB. I want to automatic dismiss progressbar Dilog not on click outside and cancel it.

Comment: So when do you want to close this progressbar? after completing some task or just by pressing back button anytime?

Comment: See my edit after you have changed the original question - `but when i press back button my progress dilog continous disply`

Answer (score 1):

Change the following:

`progressDilog.setCancelable(false)`

To:

`progressDilog.setCancelable(true)`

EDIT.

After changing the original question. Here is my answer - You have to keep track of the progress and once done you can dismiss in.

ProgressDialog doesn't dismiss itself, you have to do it manually by calling:

```
progressDilog.dismiss()
```

Once the operation is complete.

Comment: Not Work @HB. I want to automatic dismiss progressbar Dilog not on click outside and cancel it.

Comment: @MaulikDadhaniya that was not the question.